# Multidimensional arrays loading in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I want to load 3 2d arrays which should be a 2d pointer float types arrays. I want to load them as THREE 2d arrays with with 3 as the  to total number of the 2d arrays. I have these 2d arrays as raw files with names array_10 , array_100 , array_140. I write the following code for loading one array : I do not know how to load all these arrays together ...please check my code below and also it is showing error if I am putting the array kernel as 2d Pointer ** , Please help

```
int table=3, krow=99, kcol=99;
float **kernel[table][krow]kcol];

if (table ==0)
{
    sprintf(fn,"F:\\newresult\\fft\\array_10.raw");

    if ((f2=fopen( fn, "rb" ))==NULL)
    {
        printf("file does not exists %s\n",fn);
        exit(1);
    }

    for(int a = 0; a < krow; ++a)
        for(int b = 0; b < kcol; ++b)
            fread(&kernel[a][b], sizeof(float),1,f2);

    fclose(f2);

    for(int a = 0; a < krow; ++a)
        for(int b = 0; b < kcol; ++b)
            sum+=Kernel[a][b];

    for(int a = 0; a < krow; ++a)
        for(int b = 0; b < kcol; ++b)
            Kernel[a][b] /= sum;
}
```

Comment: does it really work like this ?

Comment: no its not working . Its just a first draft and its showing lots of errors

Comment: so what are you waiting to start debug ?

Comment: Code snippet you have provided does not compile, since it's missing a lot of information. Problem could be in multiple places. Please provide a **minimal** self-contained code that demonstrates the problem. And because this is about error messages, provide complete error message also.

Answer (score 1):

This is one obvious fix:

```
float kernel[table][krow][kcol];
```

instead of

```
float **kernel[table][krow]kcol];
```

Also, if you want to read the data for table N, row a and col b, you can read it like this:

fread(&kernel[N][a][b], sizeof(float),1,f2);

Comment: and `fread(&kernel[a][b], sizeof(float),1,f2);` to `fread(&[table][a][b], sizeof(float),1,f2);`

Comment: Thanks. There is an error in line float kernel[table][krow][kcol];

Comment: the `table` variable (number of tables) should be a `const int`, like your other variables `krow` and `kcol`.

Answer (score 0):

A few fixes:

```
const int krow=99, kcol=99;
float kernel[krow][kcol]; // <<< 2D array of float
char fn[PATH_MAX];
FILE *f2;
float sum;

if (table == 0)
{
    strcpy(fn, "F:\\newresult\\fft\\array_10.raw");

    if ((f2=fopen( fn, "rb" ))==NULL)
    {
         printf("file does not exists %s\n",fn);
         exit(1);
    }

    for(int a = 0; a < krow; ++a)
        for(int b = 0; b < kcol; ++b)
            fread(&kernel[a][b], sizeof(float), 1, f2); // <<< read one float

    fclose(f2);

    sum = 0; // <<< initialise sum

    for(int a = 0; a < krow; ++a)
        for(int b = 0; b < kcol; ++b)
            sum+=kernel[a][b];

    for(int a = 0; a < krow; ++a)
        for(int b = 0; b < kcol; ++b)
            kernel[a][b] /= sum;
}
```